# NodeJS streams: WritableStream output is zero bytes or non-zero bytes inconsistently

Tags: node.js

I am encountering a weird error while using NodeJS streams.

**Problem description:**

If I run this node.js script, the final file (final_x.txt) is zero bytes sometimes and is the correct output (ie., the contents of input_x.txt) sometimes. It is inconsistent.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

(() => {
    function testStreamPipingWithFS() {
        var input = fs.createReadStream('./input_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
        var output = fs.createWriteStream('./output_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
        
        pipeline(input, output, (err) => {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
        });

        var intermediate = fs.createReadStream('./output_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
        var finalFile = './final_x.txt';
        var final = fs.createWriteStream(finalFile, {autoClose: true});
        
        pipeline(intermediate, final, (err) => {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
        });
    }

    console.log(process.versions);
    testStreamPipingWithFS();

})();
```

**Environment:**

Windows version is `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.959]`

The process.versions logged by the script shows the following:

```
{
  node: '12.18.2',
  v8: '7.8.279.23-node.39',
  uv: '1.38.0',
  zlib: '1.2.11',
  brotli: '1.0.7',
  ares: '1.16.0',
  modules: '72',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  napi: '6',
  llhttp: '2.0.4',
  http_parser: '2.9.3',
  openssl: '1.1.1g',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  tz: '2019c',
  unicode: '13.0'
}
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because pipeline is asynchronous, you need to put the second call to pipeline in the callback of the first call to pipeline:

```
    function testStreamPipingWithFS() {
        
        var input = fs.createReadStream('./input_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
        var output = fs.createWriteStream('./output_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
        
        pipeline(input, output, (err) => {
            if(err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                var intermediate = fs.createReadStream('./output_x.txt', {autoClose: true});
                var finalFile = './final_x.txt';
                var final = fs.createWriteStream(finalFile, {autoClose: true});
                
                pipeline(intermediate, final, (err) => {
                if(err)
                    console.log(err);
                });
            }
        })
    }

    testStreamPipingWithFS();
```

If you don't place the second call in the callback, there is no guarantee that the first call to pipeline will complete before the second call to pipeline runs, so you will have unpredictable results.

Comment: Thank you, @crosen9999. That makes sense. I have accepted your answer.